# Did no citizen of countries banned by Trump's executive order kill any american since 1975?

Tags: united-states, history

This has been circulating on facebook and twitter:

[image]

One of the pages that shared it has 4 **million** subscribers which alone makes it notable.

Are both of the numbers correct? Both murders and those zeros?